# How to get the list of pinned applications in taskbar using C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm creating a windows application in c#, where automating windows. And I'm trying retrieve all/list of the pinned applications in the taskbar.

I searched on internet, but I didn't get any suitable solution.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using file browsing, you can find pin taskbar shortcut here :

> %AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

Credit to Cagliostro and Steven Penny

Source : https://superuser.com/questions/171096/where-is-the-list-of-pinned-start-menu-and-taskbar-items-stored-in-windows-7

Quick usage will be like :

```
private void DisplayPinnedTaskBarElements()
{
    var pinnedTaskBarItemsPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar");
    var pinnedTaskBarFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pinnedTaskBarItemsPath);
    
    foreach (var file in pinnedTaskBarFiles)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Name);
    }
}
```